# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar los registros de una tabla?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp

estoy trabajando en **Odoo 12** en el modelo `product.template` intentando ordenar los registros dentro de una tabla One2Many, la cual se encuentra en el modelo `product.supplierinfo`

Para ordenar los registros estoy usando:

```
supplier = self.env['product.supplierinfo'].search([('id', '=', id_ultimo_costo)], order='id asc')
```

La función se ejecuta sin errores, sin embargo, la tabla no se ve afectada en ningún momento, es decir, no ordena los registros.

Cabe mencionar que no quiero ordenar la **vista**, si no los **registros** de la tabla

A continuación les dejo el código que estoy usando & una imagen de la tabla:

```
@api.one
@api.depends('seller_ids')
def _order_table(self):
    _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    product_search = self.env['product.product'].search([('default_code', '=', self.default_code)], limit=1)
    all_seller_ids = product_search.seller_ids.ids

    if all_seller_ids:
        id_ultimo_costo = all_seller_ids[:]
        supplier = self.env['product.supplierinfo'].search([('id', '=', id_ultimo_costo)], order='id asc')
        sorted(supplier)

        _logger.info('IDS DE SELLERS: %s', all_seller_ids)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el campo reservado `_order` para tu modelo `'product.supplierinfo'`, de esta manera según lo que necesitas:

```
Class ProductSupplierinfo(models.Model):
    _name = 'product.supplierinfo'
    _order = 'id ASC'
```

Espero que esta respuesta pueda ayudarte.